# Kubernetes Ingress and Node Failure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to understand Kubernetes High Availability for calls that originate outside the cluster.  (For my new On-Premises Kubernetes cluster)

For Example: a desktop application needs to call a service hosted in Kubernetes.

I see two primary ways this can happen, NodePort and Ingress.

### NodePort

What will happen during a node failure with NodePort seem fairly obvious.  Any calls that are using the newly offline node as the node they are addressing will fail.  If you are using a NodePort you need to make sure you have some way of detecting that the node you are using is down, and moving traffic to another node.  (And recovering any lost traffic that happened before you detected the downtime.)

This seems like the job of a load balancer.  It can do health monitoring and send the traffic to nodes that are up.

### Ingress

I am less sure about how an Ingress Controller and an Ingress resource work.  It seems like there is a bit of magic here.  Does the Ingress controller use NodePort under the hood?  I see a lot of assumptions around a load balancer balancer that are not explained in the posts I read.  Is it expected that there will be a load balancer in place outside the cluster?

In which case what is the difference between NodePort with a load balancer and Ingress with a load balancer?  The load balancer presents a single URL to the calling systems and then it does its best to make the call get to a Kubernetes Node that is up (either via NodePort or Ingress Controller).  (Which makes me ask why both are present if both really require a load balancer to hide the node that gets called.)

But I am again confused because you use a single URL to send to an Ingress resource, so how is the node decided by the load balancer?

As I look at this, it seems that Kubernetes only has High Availability inside the cluster.  From outside the cluster, it is the job of the caller to ensure that the node they will be addressing, either via your own ping system, or a load balancer.

**Does Kubernetes have any features to help with node down times?** From the point of view of a desktop application addressing the cluster, not from the point of view of the pods keeping the service up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple pieces to this question - answering them in turn. The default service types in Kubernetes are ClusterIP, NodePort, and LoadBalancer.

#### What's a service?

> In Kubernetes, a Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them (sometimes this pattern is called a micro-service).

Basically, it's a logical load balancer in front of a collection of pods, determined by pod labels.

#### How does a ClusterIP work?

ClusterIP is an internal service, which means the IP address assigned to the service is internal to the cluster. It works by some magic in kube-proxy (read the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) if you'd like to know more). Dead pods are automatically removed from the load balancing.

#### How does NodePort work?

NodePort is an external service, which works by opening ports in the host machine. A ClusterIP is automatically created ([reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)), and through more kube-proxy magic, traffic hitting the NodePort is sent to the ClusterIP, which is in turn sent to a backend pod as appropriate.

You are correct that if the node whose NodePort you are hitting goes down, you won't be able to reach your application.

```
   traffic
      |
      v
--------------    --------------    --------------
|            |    |            |    |            |
|  NodePort  |    |  NodePort  |    |  NodePort  |
|            |    |            |    |            |
--------------    --------------    --------------
```

#### How does LoadBalancer work?

LoadBalancer is an external service, which works by load balancing traffic across the open NodePorts on each node. This means under the cover, when you create a LoadBalancer, a NodePort is created. Generally, this works with a cloud provider: a cloud provider load balancer resource is created that routes traffic to the NodePorts on each node. Health checks are built into the cloud provider load balancer to determine which nodes are up.

```
                     traffic
                        |
                        v
              --------------------
              |                  |
              |  Cloud Provider  |
              |  Load Balancer   |
              |                  |
              --------------------
      |-----------------|------------------|
      v                 v                  v
--------------    --------------    --------------
|            |    |            |    |            |
|  NodePort  |    |  NodePort  |    |  NodePort  |
|            |    |            |    |            |
--------------    --------------    --------------
```

#### How does an ingress controller work?

An ingress controller is (generally) a software component running on the cluster which provides L7 routing (as opposed to L4 routing provided by LoadBalancer). Usually, this will automatically create a LoadBalancer service because the ingress controller is a set of pods running inside the cluster.

Flow occurs something like this:

[image: Ingress controller traffic]

Image borrowed from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/application-gateway-ingress-controller-for-azure-kubernetes-service/).

Note the green arrows in front of the pods actually indicate load balancing with ClusterIPs.

#### What should I use for external traffic?

Use LoadBalancer or ingress controller. Don't use NodePort for exactly the reason you described: you have no way of knowing the node is down.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am still confused. The ingress controller traffic still has to go to one of the nodes. Even with an ingress controller. How does the ingress deal with a node outage. And how does the external load balancer know which node it is hitting if a single url is used during ingress?

Comment: The ingress controller uses an external load balancer (usually - there are exceptions depending on the specific controller, but this applies for nginx, traefik, etc). Therefore, it relies on the external load balancer to handle node outages (assuming there are ingress controller pods on multiple nodes of course, otherwise you'd have a different question).

Comment: The external load balancer doesn't care which node it is hitting. It can hit any living node and kube-proxy will route appropriately. There's a built-in healthcheck for the backend, so the external load balancer will know not to route to a dead node.

Comment: The single url/IP address corresponding to the ingress controller is actually associated with the LoadBalancer. Based on above, flow is: external traffic -> external loadbalancer -> Kubernetes LoadBalancer -> NodePort -> ingress controller ClusterIP -> ingress controller pods (which determines proper routing based on path/host as appropriate) -> application ClusterIP (the exact one is determined by controller pods) -> application pod.

Comment: So in the end, all the Inbound traffic uses a node port to get into the Kubernetes cluster. But Ingress only needs one for many services  (because it does service routing after the call gets into the cluster). When using a normal node port system, you need a node port per service. (But both rely on node ports to get into the Kubernetes cluster.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right the ingress controller will create the LoadBalancer out of the cluster.

Ingress controller will manage the ingress object inside the cluster and you can redirect the traffic and manage it inside the cluster.

**Does Kubernetes have any features to help with node down times**

run multiple replicas across the nodes if one of your nodes fails other PODs on another node will be up and serving until the old unhealthy node come back to its normal state.

Sorry, i am not getting the meaning of (In which case what is the difference between NodePort with a load balancer and Ingress with a load balancer?) single URL node port and ingress part. if you want to understand the ingress in simple words you can consider it as the **NGINX**. You can define the multiple site domain and redirect rules with the different SSL/TLS certificates.